# Explain php if statement

Tags: php

Can someone please explain in detail what these if statements are doing?

What does the three === signs to in the first one, and What does the single & in the second mean?

```
$aProfile = getProfileInfo($iId);
    if($aProfile === false)
        return false;

    if(!((int)$aProfile['Role'] & $iRole))
        return false;
```

Comment: Why the downvote? There are many *novice* PHP developers who are confused with `==` and `===` .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`===` tests for type-safe equality.

`'3' == 3` will return true, but `'3' === 3` will not, because one's a string and one's an integer. Similarly, `null == 0` will return true, but `null === 0` will not; `10.00 == 10` will return true, but `10.00 === 10` will not.

`&` is the bitwise AND operator. It returns a bitmask in which a bit is set if *both* the corresponding bits are set from the original two bitmasks.

For example:

```
$x = 5;
$y = 17;
echo $x & $y;
```

causes 1 to be echoed. `$x` is `...000101`, `$y` is `...010001`. The only bit that is set in *both* of them is the rightmost one, so you get `...000001`, which is 1.

Comment: And my favorite along those lines: `1.0 === 4/4` is false... `1 === 4/4` is true...  (Of course, `1.0 == 4/4` is true)... (The reason it's my favorite, is `1.5 === 6/4` is true.  So division sometimes returns a float, other times an int...)

Comment: @ircmaxell: Looks peculiar but it's nothing unique to PHP nor does it have anything to really do with PHP implementation. It's simply the PHP `===` being able to expose the underlying storage mechanisms. The result of `4/4` doesn't require floating point storage so it isn't used.

Comment: @webbiedave: Oh I know.  But it's definitely not something that I expect to happen (I would assume that division always returns a float).  I'm not saying that there's anything "wrong", just something to watch out for because it can be confusing at first (if you use `===` or type checks (`is_float`)...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good guide to PHP operators:

http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/3/12/3

See the section on bitwise operators for info on the &.

Comment: Nice link!

The === (identical) operator is used very rarely in comparison to == (equality), but it can be useful on occasion. To make sure you are clear, two variables are only identical if they hold the same value and if they are the same type.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. It should be noted, however, that the === operator really does what beginners expect == to do (it checks for equality of identity and type...so 1 === true is false whereas 1 == true is true). It's important for a beginner to give a good look at all the possible truth statements before using the == operator with any frequency...otherwise they may run into problems that aren't immediately simple to solve.